# Machine learning multi-classification: Why use 'one-hot' encoding instead of a number

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, multiclass-classification

I'm currently working on a classification problem with tensorflow, and i'm new to the world of machine learning, but I don't get something.

I have successfully tried to train models that output the `y` tensor like this:

```
y = [0,0,1,0]
```

But I can't understand the principal behind it...

Why not just train the same model to output classes such as `y = 3` or `y = 4`

This seems much more flexible, because I can imagine having a multi-classification problem with 2 million possible classes, and it would be much more efficient to output a number between 0-2,000,000 than to output a tensor of 2,000,000 items for every result.

What am I missing?

Comment: you only need to set only one bit to classify and , if you think about your output layer only one function should activate and all the others will be 0. 
onehot is often use in state coding on fpga in quicker and secure way to label stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you could train you model to classify input instances and producing a single output. Something like

`y=1` means `input=dog`, `y=2` means `input=airplane`. An approach like that, however, brings a lot of problems:

1. How do I interpret the output `y=1.5`?
2. Why I'm trying the *regress* a number like I'm working with continuous data while I'm, in reality, working with discrete data?

In fact, what are you doing is treating a multi-class *classification problem* like a regression problem.
This is locally wrong (unless you're doing binary classification, in that case, a positive and a negative output are everything you need).

To avoid these (and other) issues, we use a final layer of neurons and we associate an high-activation to the right class.

The one-hot encoding represents the fact that you want to force your network to have a single high-activation output when a certain input is present.

This, every `input=dog` will have `1, 0, 0` as output and so on.

In this way, you're correctly treating a discrete classification problem, producing a discrete output and well interpretable (in fact you'll always extract the output neuron with the highest activation using `tf.argmax`, even though your network hasn't learned to produce the perfect one-hot encoding you'll be able to extract without doubt the most likely correct output )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in how that final tensor, or single value, are calculated. In an NN, your `y=3` would be build by a weighted sum over the values of the previous layer.

Trying to train towards single values would then imply a linear relationship between the category IDs where none exists: For the true value `y=4`, the output `y=3` would be considered better than `y=1` even though the categories are random, and may be `1: dogs, 3: cars, 4: cats`

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks use gradient descent to optimize a loss function. In turn, this loss function needs to be differentiable.

A discrete output would be (indeed is) a perfectly valid and valuable output for a classification network. Problem is, we don't know how to optimize this net efficiently.

Instead, we rely on a continuous loss function. This loss function is usually based on something that is more or less related to the probability of each label -- and for this, you need a network output that has one value per label.

Typically, the output that you describe is then deduced from this soft, continuous output by taking the argmax of these pseudo-probabilities.